# I am a Product Manager with 6+ years in Product Management; am I eligible for PMP certification?

Tags: pmp, certification, product-manager

I have been full time product manager for last 6 years, with total of 9 years of industry experience. I could not find good software project/product nanager certifications which are accepted globally, so I was thinking of getting a PMP certification.

I have gone to the [PMI web site](http://www.pmi.org/default.aspx), but there are no clear answers about whether the PMP certification is for Product Managers. As a Product Manager, should I pursue PMP certification?

Answer (score 2):

The [PMP certification](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/Project-Management-Professional-PMP.aspx) is specifically for project management. If you're a product manager, you probably want to pursue a certificate program related to program or portfolio management rather than project management. A non-exhaustive list of such programs include:

- [Certified Scrum Product Owner (CSPO)](http://www.scrumalliance.org/certifications/practitioners/cspo-certification)
- [Program Management Professional (PgMP)](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/Program-Management-Professional-PgMP.aspx)
- [Portfolio Management Professional (PfMP)](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/Portfolio-Management-Professional-PfMP.aspx)

There are certainly others, and I'm not endorsing any of these programs personally. You should definitely do your own research to see what programs are most suitable for your individual career path and market segment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best first step is to look at the syllabus for any of the PM bootcamps that are out there to help you meet the minimum requirement for PM coursework you need to qualify for PMP certification. If the course contents look useful to your being a good product manager there may be value.

There are also some other alternatives, such as CAPM (another certification offered by PMI) and PRINCE2 (offered by APM Group), that you may want to consider in lieu of PMP certification.